# How to Reference/pull/sort by a specific key in a multidimensional array

Tags: php

I am writing a page that pulls images and image data out of a multidimensional array. I need to be able to click a button that calls a function to sort out the images by tags(IE tag_GlassDoor & tag_GlassWall) - basically to show only images that do or do not have that particular element (in this case im using 0 and 1 for yes and no), such as a glass door.  I can currently make that array display the data, but I cant figure out how to sort the data by one of the array keys, or even really the syntax to pull a single value out at will.

```
   $arrImages[] = 
    [
        'img_sm'=>'image1.jpg', 
        'tag_GlassDoor'=>0,
        'tag_GlassWall'=>1,
    ];
   $arrImages[] = 
    [
        'img_sm'=>'image2.jpg', 
        'tag_GlassDoor'=>1,
        'tag_GlassWall'=>1,
    ];
```

Comment: This isn't sorting, it's filtering. Use `array_filter()`.

Comment: But if you wanted to sort, `usort` allows you to use a user function that tells how to compare between every 2 items for the sorting

Answer (score 1):

Filtering is the answer, it can be used to filter one dimensional Arrays and multidimensional arrays.
the general implementation would be something like this:

```
$arr = array(
    array(
        'image' => "data",
        'hasObject' => 1
    ),
    array(
        'image' => "data",
        'hasObject' => 0 
    ),
);
$finteredArray = array_filter($arr, function ($r) {
   return (bool) $r['hasObject'];
});

print_r($finteredArray);
// it outputs:
// Array ( [0] => Array ( [image] => data [hasObject] => 1 ) )
```